# Laravel return latest

Tags: laravel

I've got this on my forum model:

```
public function messages()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Message::class);
}
```

How could I return by latest. Already tried `->latest();` but that does not work any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `orderBy()` directly:

```
public function messages()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Message::class)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```